# Marketo Token Link Ignoring Styles

Tags: email-templates, marketo

Currently Trying to Insert a Calendar Token for an `Add to Calendar` link, within a button. However, the token ignores the styles of the parent it's placed within, so it's blue and underlined. I want to correct these styles that are coming in with the token, but nothing I do works. I tried putting an extra `<span>` around the token (which was posted as a previous solution to this problem), but when the token renders its `<a>` tag, the styles from the `<span>` don't effect it.

How do you avoid this issue with token's that bring in links? Gotta be an easy solution for this right?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the calendar link text in a span within the calendar token to change the color.

[image: Example]

Comment: thank you! But how do you get to that field? Where you create the generic tokens or is that a field within the html editor? 

I also found another way, when you `insert/edit hyperlink` in the rich text editor — you can insert the token and edit the token's styles that way.

Comment: Where you create the calendar token.